# How many different ways can $3 be made using any number of coins?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

There are eight coins in general circulation:

1p, 2p, 5p, 10p, 20p, 50p, $1 (100p) and $2 (200p).

It is possible to make $2 in the following way: 
1x$1 + 1x50p + 2x20p + 1x5p + 1x2p + 3x1p

How many different ways can $3 be made using any number of coins?

how can we do it using PHP?

Comment: This is clearly a puzzle question, not a programming question. If you have trouble *implementing* the algorithm, please ask here. If you're just asking a puzzle question that can as well be answered with pen and paper, this is the wrong site.

Comment: are we missing the homework tag?

Comment: @DavidChan: It may be, as it looks a very similar (but slightly modified) Project Euler problem 31.

Comment: Subset Sum Problem. Look it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem and those like it are best solved using [generating functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function).

For this case, you want to consider terms of the form

```
1/(1 - x^k) = 1 + x^k + x^(2k) + x^(3k) + ...
```

where `k` is one of the values `1p, 2p, 5p, 10p, 20p, 50p, 100p, 200p`. Now multiply all of these 8 terms together to get

```
f(x) = 1 / [ (1-x) * (1-x^2) * (1-x^5) * ... * (1-x^200) ]
```

Then the coefficient of `x^m` is exactly the number of ways `mp` can be made from the given denominations. For example, the coefficient of `x^200` is `6`, which corresponds to the fact that there are exactly `6` ways to get `200p = $2` from the given denominations.

---

Here's a quick and dirty explanation for why this works. The coefficient of `x^m` in `f(x)` is the number of ways to take one term of the form `x^(i*k)` from each linear factor of the form `(1 - x^k)` in the denominator so that the sum of the exponents is `m`, i.e.

```
i1*k1 + i2*k2 + ... + i8*k8 = m
```

Now the term with `k1 = 1` corresponds to taking `1p`, the term with `k2 = 2` corresponds to taking `2p`, the term with `k3=5p` corresponds to taking `5p`, and so on. The sum above becomes

```
i1*(1p) + i2*(2p) + i3*(5p) + ... + i8*(200p) = m
```

which gives the amounts to take of each denomination.